# Legendary drops

Tags: fallout-shelter

I have 15+ dwellers with 70 S.P.E.C.I.A.L. and lvl 50, I send them out regularly at approx 1 hour interval between each other.
I made more than 100 wasteland expeditions over the 60 hours mark, but so far I've got no legendary item...

Is the legendary drop rate for the National Guard Depot so low?

Comment: IIRC legendaries are also time-related. The longer you stay out, the more that drop. If you are sending your dwellers out for a specific time, and not increasing the overall time they spend, i dont think you are increasing your chances of dropping legendaries

Answer (score 1):

NGD drops were reduced in a patch.

Getting legendary items now is almost impossible.

Even lunchboxes have a low legendary drop rate - I usually get 500 caps from the gold card.

Look for Fallout Shelter negative time glitch on YouTube, maybe it still works.

Comment: That's a pity... but I don't think I will exploit the game to gain some legendary.
Anyway many of my expeditions have been made before the latest patch

Comment: I agree, haven't used the exploit myself. I have done a few expeditions since patch 1.2 and did not notice any changes  except for the Santa and Elf suits dropping.

Comment: Do you have any evidence, like changelogs from patches, to support your statements?

Comment: Empirical observations while playing the game combined with reading posts from users that were playing FS before it was released on Android on the Bethesda forums. There's a Google docs spreadsheet analyzing the drop rate before patch 1.1 and the drops now are nowhere near that level. And I had 109 dwellers exploring the wastes before they introduced the 25 explorer limit.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Nai09D_aM2syl3iPP5hkveDcOUwhsoUDR6s1lwC0e8c/edit?pli=1#gid=1591448540) should help though it is a lot to read. I will post the relevant parts of the Google Doc here just in case the link somehow dies.

The chance of getting a rare or legendary item increases over time in the National Guard Depot (I will call it NGP for short). The chance of getting a legendary item is about:

- Duration Time/360000

The chance increases every six hours by 0.1 percent for legendary ***weapons***. Armor has not shown up. The negative time glitch could also force a legendary to appear and be obtained by the player. You might also be facing a maximum legendary cap of one legendary item per expedition. On fixed time events though, the chance for a legendary increase by 10 times:

- 10*(Duration Time/360000)

Comment: As you say, after 60 hours the chance at legendary weapon should be 10*0.1 = 1% plus with the NGD fixed event multiplier, 10% to get a legendary weapon. If this is true, I am really unlucky to have found anything after 100+ expeditions.
I was aware of the doc, but the numbers and my experience are telling two different stories...

Comment: That data is for an older version of the game, it may not be completely accurate.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think its possible to get a legendary in the wasteland, but if you can get one, then you probably are very very very lucky. It's better to just do quests than to explore in the wasteland but the wasteland is good in the beginning of the game or if you just want to get some rare items.

I don't think that the negative time glitch works but you can find that out on YouTube.